# Android get Tab position within fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a view pager that uses the following fragments:

Fragment1 - ViewPager holder

Fragment2

What I want to do is get the tab position from with fragment2 or fragment3

e.g. In Fragment2 check if is at position 1

I know this sounds odd but I have one fragment that will display on each of the two tabs, the reason for doing this is that the fragment code is exactly the same and displays dynamic data based on a 'switch' (tab1 = Items to select, tab2 - Items that have been selected).  I cant get the second tab to display data, as it need to know which tab it is in to act on the 'switch' - Creating two separate fragments with exactly the same code seems like overkill, there must be an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you instantiate your Fragments just add a position param

something similar to

```
Fragment frag = MyFragment.getInstance(currentPosition);
```

in `MyFragment`

```
public MyFragment(int position) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1);
    bundle.put(POS_ARG, position);
}
```

then use it where ever you want